# Cartoon Edges post processing edge thickness missing option

Tags: rendering, edges

so... I was trying to render with the cartoon edges, it works fine.
BUT in the Blender help it says that there's an option for the edge thickness, but that option is missing in the software, at least I couldn't find it, so for now I'm using Freestyle. 
Does anybody know where to find it?
If not, can it be re-implemented?

Comment: I guess that "blender help" was about a very old (pre v2.5 version)? nowadays, freestyle coud be the only way...

Comment: by any chance is [this](http://download.blender.org/documentation/html/x6578.html) the documentation you read? That is for blender 2.28, not 2.78, huge differences.

Comment: Are you using freestyle?